# primefaces modal dialog not displaying the correct growl message

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
I have two dialogs both are modal dialog.
Dialog 1:dialog1.xhtml
<ui:composition>
<p:dialog modal="true">
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('dialog2widgetVar').open()" />
<ui:include src="dialog2.xhtml"></ui:include>
</p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
Dialog 2:dialog2.xhtml
<ui:composition>
<p:dialog modal="true">
```

when the second dialog is opened the growl is appearing behind the dialog.

how to make growl to appear in the front of the second dialog?

Comment: make inside your dialog a form and a growl before the form

Comment: [mcve] please... lots of weird non-function/wrong code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was having the same issue and I found a workaround:

```
.ui-growl {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

I know that is not a fancy way to solve this problem but it works :)